# Position relative not taking automatic width of a div

Tags: html, css

I have created navigation menu on hover the span will comeup but the problem is that when I set widht to auto the text is breaking up why is that so if i set with 150px it is okay then but will create problem for small texts can anyone help me out

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/afdz86pg/][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/afdz86pg/
```

Comment: which width are you taking about ? And what do you mean by 'the test is breaking up' ?

Comment: Why you don't use bootstrap tool-tip, It will provide consistency https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tooltip_pos&stacked=h

Comment: the width of tooltip you will notice add to is in one line and portfolio on second line is it should be in same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st `span, a` are `inline block elements`, 2nd you need to add `position:relative` to `parent` element to set `child` element which `span` over-here, `position:absolute` too, to set `width` same as `parent` element, 3rd to get `text` in one line use `white-space:nowrap` in `span` tag as you have set it display:block, as below,

```
white-space:nowrap - Sets all character into single-line.
```

```css
.co_nav {
    float: right;
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:80px;
}

.co_nav > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.co_nav > ul > li {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    position: relative;
}

.co_nav > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #b8b8b8;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
     position:relative;
     display:block;
}

.co_nav > ul > li > a:hover {
    color: #fcbf3c;
}

.co_nav > ul > li > a > span {
    width:auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: -27px;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background-color: rgba(13, 25, 39, 0.13);
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
    -webkit-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-in-out all .5s;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.co_nav > ul > li > a:hover > span {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="co_nav">
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="">A
        <span>Add To Portfolio</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">B
        <span>Add To Watchlist</span>
       </a>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="">c
        <span>Create Alerts</span>
       </a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: your rock thank you so much for your help and also explaining me

Comment: Welcome @MarkAlan :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the given link: https://jsfiddle.net/afdz86pg/
and found what the problem is happening on your code.
Please remove the

> position:relative;

from your css e.i. in class `.co_nav > ul > li.`

I hope it is helpful for you.

Thanks,